Expressions with operands on both sides of assignment operator
Is the following expression valid in C:
uint32_t arr[4] = {0};
uint32_t val = 0;

arr[val++] = val+=1;

If so, how is it evaluated? I went through C Operator Precedence but couldn't find if its valid or how to evaluate.
In GCC 14.2 the array looks like the following once its executed:
0
2
0
0


Application of linked duplicate to your case: By operator precedence and associativity arr[val++] = val+=1; is equivalent to (arr[val++]) = (val+=1);. There is no specified order in which right- and left-hand side of = are evaluated. Therefore there are two unsequenced modifications of val in the expression, which causes undefined behavior.

As a rule of thumb, you should just not write code where you have to check the reference material to understand what it does. Even if the compiler knows, the poor human readers will not.
